# Byte array in VBA Access

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba, byte

How to pass byte array as function parameter in **VBA**?

In **VB** function is writing EPC HEX word to RFID tag:

```
Public Shared Function WriteEPC_G2(ByRef ConAddr As Byte, **ByVal Password() As Byte**, **ByVal WriteEPC() As Byte**, ByVal WriteEPClen As Byte, ByRef errorcode As Integer, ByVal PortHandle As Ineger) As Integer
```

Bolded parameters are made with function which generate byte array from textboxes (password "00000000" and ECP to write "i.e. 1234")

```
Private Function HexStringToByteArray(ByVal s As String) As Byte()
    s = s.Replace(" ", "")
    Dim buffer(s.Length / 2 - 1) As Byte
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To s.Length - 2 Step 2
        buffer(i / 2) = Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16)
    Next
    Return buffer
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA has a built-in function that does this:

```
buffer = StrConv(string, vbFromUnicode)
```